# Browser Rdeirecting to unwanted site "http://wonderlandads.com/afu.php?zoneid=437742"

Tags: security, browser, malware, antivirus

I have chrome installed on my windows 7. Whenever i click on any link on any site, the link opens as it should open normally but along with that, a new tab opens and a page open that new tab, which is advertisement page. The url of that page is `wonderlandads dot com/afu.php?zoneid=437742` . Even when i click on scroll bar the same page opens in new tab.This is very irritating. I have tried to remove this adware by using Anti Malware Quickheal . I have also scanned my PC with antivirus. I do not have any unwanted software in my PC. I have tried reinstalling chrome and other browsers(IE, firefox) that i have. I am experiencing the same problem in firefox and IE. How can i fix it ?

Comment: url changed so as not to infect the rest of us

Answer (score 2):

Just search for "uninstall wonderlandads.com" on Google - it installs as a program on your computer, so you need to go to Programs in the Control Panel and uninstall it.

Comment: ya it solve the problem but may i know is it malware or virus?

Comment: Problem again arises after some time .

Comment: It almost certainly installs as part of something else. When you look at the programs in the Control Panel, click the Installed On header to sort the programs by the date they were installed and whatever app is installed on the same date as the ads is probably the app that is installing it - then don't use that software anymore either! I'd say it is malware rather than a virus, although often this kind of software is exploited by other things too, so it's more than just annoying.